# She wants... = "Elle en veut..."?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, compléments, en

In this sentence "elle a déjà un livre mais elle en veut un nouveau", why is there "en" between "elle" and "veut"?
"Elle en veut un nouveau" translates to "She wants a new one". So why not "Elle veut un nouveau"?

Comment: For the same reason the english sentence is not "She wants a new". "one" in English and "en" in French both refer to the book you spoke of before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this context, *en*, just like the English "one" you used, is a nicer way to repeat "the book".

You could totally say "elle a déjà un livre, mais elle veut un nouveau livre", which is correct grammatically and very understandable.

However, the repetition is something one would like to avoid, for it is clearly not subtle. That is why, just like other *groupes pronominaux* can be replaced by *le*, *la* or *les*, you can replace *un nouveau livre* by *en*.

In case you are interested by further information about the use of *en* and its "grammatical properties" (in this context - please note *en* is a very used word in French and has a lot of meanings and uses for it covers a wide range of roles in the sentence) :

- *en* is an *pronom personnel*, it means it goes before the *verbe*
- *en* is an invariable *pronom personnel* : there is not masculine/feminine or singular/plural ! This is rare for a *pronom personnel* !
- it replaces a *complément d'objet direct* (if you need help with the French pronouns and *compléments d'objet*, this can help I guess http://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/understanding-french-pronouns)
- when *en* is **not** a *pronom personnel*, it is a *préposition* ! You can find more examples about this form here : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en#Pr.C3.A9position

Hope I could help !

Comment: Thanks! I only started learning so I am only familiar with the form that is more understandable.

Comment: thta is why i thought I would give you further info ! You are welcome